# Displaying a Flatlist Data to Flatlist Props

Tags: javascript, react-native

im having an issue with passing my Flatlist data to my Flatlist props which is 'ListHeaderComponent'. here's my code:

```
        <FlatList
            ListHeaderComponent={
                <View>
                    <Text>{}</Text>
                </View>
            }
            data={displayedPhoto}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            renderItem={renderPhotoItem}
            numColumns={2}
            
        />
```

is there any possible to pass my Flatlist Data inside the Text Component? Help me please

Comment: looking at the docs, it accepts component, not function, so I do not think there is a way to do it directly.. however, you can create a variable beforehand and pass it that way.. I have to also mention that the ListHeaderComponent is for the whole flatlist.. in case you are trying to add a header for each item on the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListHeaderComponent is a prop which use to render the component as Header of the FlatList which scrolls with the FlatList. ListHeaderComponent can't have the item of the FlatList. You can use like

```
renderHeader = () => {
   return (
     <View>
       <Text>Employees</Text>
     </View>
   );
 };


<FlatList
  ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
  data={displayedPhoto}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  renderItem={renderPhotoItem}
  numColumns={2}
/>
```